# Setting default browser for QGIS actions

Tags: qgis, pdf

I am trying to open a pdf using QGIS action tool with Adobe Reader. Currently, the action defaults to Internet Explorer which doesn't succeed in opening my document. I'm currently able to open AutoCAD files and photos. Does anyone know how to set the default software used to by QGIS actions? I'm using QGIS version 2.0.

my pathname in the attribute field is: 
explorer C:\Documents and Settings\user\Bureau\file.pdf

Action Type: Windows. Name: Open file. Action: [%"pathname"%]. I didn't click the Capture checkbox.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does it work if you remove "explorer" from the attribute field?

Comment: No, i get a dialog box saying "unable to run command"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While i'm still not able to set a default browser, I've succeeded in directing it to the file's default browser (under file properties) by entering the pathname as: cmd /c "fullpathname"